# Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server /oauth/token - 500 No adapter for handler

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement Spring Security's OAuth2 Authorization Server. When attempting to access the token endpoint (/oauth/token) I get a 404. I assume there is something I am missing, but for the life of me, I can't see it.

I am using Java configuration for;

- Spring Security 4.0.1
- Spring Security OAuth2 2.0.7

My configuration is as follows:

ApplicationSecurityConfig.java

Used to register the configuration files in the WAR

```
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends 
    AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public ApplicationSecurityConfig() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class, AuthorizationServerConfig.class);
    }
}
```

SpringSecurityConfig.java

Configuring httpbasic authentication for all endpoints matching the URL pattern /

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .authenticated()
        .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

OauthAuthorizationServerConfig.java

Used to configure the authorization server

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OauthAuthorizationServerConfig extends 
    AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;  

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception{

        clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("testClient")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600); 
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore(){
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception{
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception{
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

 }
```

Apologies if this is a 'school boy error' but I have spent some time looking at the Documentation and the Samples that Spring have posted on Github, but I'm obviously misunderstanding something.

***--EDIT--***

I have replaced 
ApplicationSecurityConfig.java with SpringApplicationInit.java

```
public class SpringApplicationInit extends 
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
            SpringSecurityConfig.class,
            OauthAuthorizationServerConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

This yeilds different results. I now get a 500 Server error status code:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandlerAdapter(DispatchrServlet.java:1163)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

I have pushed the code to a git repo if it makes it easier to follow.

Comment: did u check the PREFIX of the /oauth/token? make sure it is a valid URI.

Comment: Yes. I have some REST endpoints residing under /rest which I can access.

Comment: the first call - /oauth/authorize - works?

Comment: I am using password grant, so the first call is to the token endpoint. An example request would be:
    domain/project/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=testClient&username=user&password=password*

Comment: you send GET request?!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you tries to send `GET` request to `/oauth/token`
which is wrong approach. 
This endpoint should accept `POST` request so just post to it with the same fields.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/mszarlinski/oauth2-separate-example) is my example of *minimal* configuration for separate authentication and resource servers - only necessary things to make this work.

Comment: External link may be out of date. Please copy main content to SO and provide the link as reference.